# Man pages in Linux

Tags: linux, fedora, setup, man

I don't seem to have all the man pages that I need.

For example, my college computers (running [Fedora](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29) 14) have [man pages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Man_page) for [ASCII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII), all the standard C libraries (stdlib.h, stdio.h) and so on and so forth.

I wish to "install" these pages, after looking up on the Internet I couldn't really find anything that made sense.

How can I get, say, the man-page of ASCII (I know it's not really a command or a daemon or anything like that, but typing man ASCII on the college computer gets me a page with the ASCII value table + a little more information).

I don't want to keep using the Internet for looking up man pages every time I need to look up a function, function prototype or the ASCII table or something like that.

Comment: Have you searched your package manager for "manpages"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least in Fedora you should use the package manager to install the package "man-pages".

If you do not want to use the package manager for some reason and want the upstream package you can download it from: http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/download.html